# How to have one element in a horizontal StackPanel dictate the height of another element in the StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

In a StackPanel, I would like the Height of the TextBlock to dictate the height of the Image, but trying to bind the Image Height to the TextBlock ActualHeight causes the Image to disappear. The height of the TextBlock will vary depending on the size of the font being used.

The StackPanel is defined as follows:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        <Image Source="{Binding HyperlinkIconImagePath}" 
               Height="{Binding ElementName=hyperlinkTextBlock, Path=ActualHeight}" 
               Margin="{StaticResource IconLeftMargin}" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <TextBlock>
            <Hyperlink 
                NavigateUri="{Binding HyperlinkUri}">
                <TextBlock 
                    Name="hyperlinkTextBlock" 
                    Text="{Binding HyperlinkDisplayedText}"/>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
```

I have tried many different things and none will work. Any help is greatly appreciated.  Note that this StackPanel is contained in a ControlTemplate.

Comment: The image will "disappear" if the TextBlock.Height is zero. Add some local text value to it to test it. Your code should work.

Comment: Would using a Grid instead of a StackPanel make sense?

Comment: I tried to add a hard coded text string to the hyperlinkTextBlock but doing so made no difference.

Comment: This StackPanel is contained in a ControlTemplate, so I'm wondering if that fact is what is causing this not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue came from a rather subtle direction. I was initially trying to bind to the ActualHeight value of the TextBlock. During the layout process, the ActualHeight value was apparently not yet determined when it was referenced by the Image Height attribute. I then thought about using the size of the font being displayed in the TextBlock, and this FontSize value apparently is already established and usable.

```
<Image Source="{Binding HyperlinkIconImagePath}" 
       Height="{Binding ElementName=HyperlinkTextBlock, Path=FontSize}" 
       Margin="{StaticResource IconLeftMargin}" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

I therefore changed the Image Height binding to reference the TextBlock font size, and this resulted in a successful rendering.

Answer (score 0):

try `VerticalAlignment="Center"` :

<TextBloc VerticalAlignment="Center" .../>